# where can I use try catch in dynamic memory allocation program?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

i'm new to the world of c ++ so i need a little help. I wrote a program with dynamic memory allocation that does the following:

- Print a message to the user to enter the array size
- User input the array size
- Filling an array of n elements with zeros
- Printing an array
- Print a message to the user to enter n elements
- User input n elements and their placement in the array
- Print the total number of even numbers entered
- Print the total number of odd numbers entered
- Delete a dynamic array

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main()
> {
> int even_counter = 0;
> int odd_counter = 0;
> int* a = NULL;
> cout << "Enter size of an array:"<< endl;
> int n;
> cin >> n;
> a = new int[n];
> for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
>     a[i] = 0;
>     cout << a[i]<<endl;
> }
> cout<< "Enter the elements of an array:"<<endl;
> for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
>     cin>>a[i];
> }
> for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
>       if (i % 2 == 1) {
>       even_counter = even_counter + 1;
>       }
>       if (i % 2 == 0) {
>       odd_counter = odd_counter + 1;
>       }
> }
> cout << You've entered " << even_counter << " even and " << odd_counter <<
> " odd numbers." << endl;
> delete [] a;
> a = NULL;
> return 0;
> }
> ```

I wanted to ask if my program is completely correct and how could I use the try catch command in this program. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not related to the memory allocation, but `if(i % 2 == 1)` doesn't test if the `i`th element of `a` is even. It's true when `i` itself is odd and positive, with no reference to whatever the user entered for `a[i]`.

Comment: you're correct but when I put if (i% 2 == 0) for even numbers then it counts my odd numbers. You can try it yourself

Comment: I'm saying `i % 2 == 0` isn't counting any numbers inside `a` at all. It's counting how many even and odd indices there are. If you happen to give it input like `1 2 3 4 5` where there's an odd value at every even index, it will coincidentally look like the program is "counting your odd numbers". But if you give it input like `2 4 6 8 10` you'll see that it's not.

Comment: thanks I didn't noticed that but how can I fix this ?

Comment: `if(i % 2 == 0)` is testing whether `i` is even. You want to test whether `a[i]` is even.